# Fullname multilingual Regexp

Tags: node.js, regex

Currently the validation of fullname looks like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/
```

But that regexp validates only latin alphabet names. This should be changed in order to handle multilingual characters also. I have tried:

```
/^(\p{L}\p{M}*){2,30}$/u
```

But it validates numbers within names also, which is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

As in the first case, use a character class with Unicode as well:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Zs}]{2,30}$/u
```

The `\p{Zs}` denotes a space char, such as regular space   and Japanese space char 　.

In case you want to prevent space at the start and end, use these negative lookaheads:

```
/^(?!\p{Zs})(?!.*\p{Zs}$)[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Zs}]{2,30}$/u
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/A4QDIf/1).

Comment: Added a demo link +1.

Comment: Thanks @Jan! You could add a typical Japanese name: `明美橋本`

Comment: Done that. I am not very into Japanese. None at all, to be honest.